# Storing certificate chains in the application keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl-certificate, keychain, truststore

On iOS, I know that we can evaluate a trust with SecTrustEvaluate(). To create a trust, we either import it from a *.p12 file or create it using an array of certificates and a set of policies.

I also know that in order to ensure that a server, that is not trusted by default, is trusted, we can use SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates() to augment the list of root CAs SecTrustEvaluate() uses to verify the server's certificate.

Now, how can I ensure that these anchor certificates are available on a subsequent launch? I can store certificates, keys and identities in the application keychain, but not a certificate chain. Even if I store all the certificates in the chain, how will I know what certificates are to be used as anchor certificates?

One solution that comes to mind is to just get *all* the certificates from the keychain and set them as anchor certificates. Another method could be to all the certificate chains on the disk as *.p12 files and load them once on every application run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eskimo1 from Apple Devforums answered this so:

First up, you don't need to store the certificates in the keychain.  You can store them elsewhere if you like (and create the SecCertificateRef using SecCertificateCreateWithData).

Secondly, your question talks about .p12 files, but I'm not sure what this has to do with things.  In general you only use a .p12 file to distribute confidential information, and certificates are not confidential.

Finally, you can store a certificate chain by just storing the persistent reference to each certificate in that chain (or by storing the actual data of each certificate).